# How do I know which libraries are included in python safety-db

Tags: python

I started using safety (https://pypi.org/project/safety/) through pipenv check to check for vulnerabilities in my python dependencies.

However, how do I know which libraries are included (in safety-db)?

If no issues are reported, can I assume all my dependencies were scanned?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of libraries in safetydb from [here](https://github.com/pyupio/safety-db/blob/master/data/insecure.json) and CVE details from [here](https://github.com/pyupio/safety-db/blob/master/data/insecure_full.json)

Comment: Just because a package isn't in the insecure list, doesn't mean it has been reviewed so it could still have undiscovered safety issues just because not many people are using it. If the system only relies on documented issues (and not reviewing packages) then it's very misleading and probably only useful for large libraries e.g. Django